# Sending a JSON thru jQuery POST is not hitting the REST service

Tags: json, rest, jquery, post

I looked up similar errors on the forum, but seems not be working still and I am getting
 `Status Code: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type`

I am sending this jQuery:

```
$("#btnInsertCustomer").click(function (){
            var myObj = {name: "Bill Adama", address:"Vancouver Canada"};
            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(myObj);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8081/RestDemo/services/customers/add",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: jsondata,
                success: function (resp, status, xhr) {
                    var msg = "Name: " + resp.name + ", Address: " + resp.address;
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#successPost").html(msg  + " - STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

                },
                error: function(resp, status, xhr){  
                    alert("Error: " + resp.e); 
                    $("#errorPost").html("Error: " + resp.e  + " - STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

                } 
            });
         });
```

to this following resource:

```
@POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String addCustomer(Customer customer) {
         //insert 
         int id = customerMap.size();
         customer.setId(id);
         customerMap.put(id, customer);
         //get inserted
         Customer result = customerMap.get(id);

         return  "{\"name\": \" " + result.getName() + " \", \"address\": \"" + result.getAddress() + "\"}";
}
```

it is not hitting the serivce and in giving me the error. I can't understand if the error is in formatting the sent data on jQuery side (which seem to be ok) or in the service receiver.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

**UPDATE 1: CREATED A DTO TO TRANSFER**

```
 $("#btnInsertCustomer").click(function (){
            //var myObj = '{"name": "Bill Adama", "address":"Vancouver Canada"}';
            //var jsondata = JSON.stringify(myObj);

            var NewCustomer = { };
            NewCustomer.name = "Bill Adama";
            NewCustomer.address = "Vancouver Canada";
            var DTO = { 'NewCustomer' : NewCustomer };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost:8081/RestDemo/services/customers/add",
                data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (resp, status, xhr) {
                    var msg = "Name: " + resp.name + ", Address: " + resp.address;
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#successPost").html(msg  + " - STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

                },
                error: function(resp, status, xhr){  
                    alert("Error: " + resp.e); 
                    $("#errorPost").html(resp.e  + " - STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

                } 
            });
         });
```

but I still get the same error!

Comment: even this way is nt actually hitting the brakpoint in the web service...while a GET does work fine.

Comment: Testing this with Poster (Firefox) gives back the same error...so apparently the problem is in the Resource class in accepting json. Any one can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your service is expecting `customer`, You have to create an object in your javascript.
this [LINK](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/) will help you.

Also couple of points to correct you :

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

This >> myObj = {name: "Bill Adama", address:"Vancouver Canada"};

myObj = '{"name": "Bill Adama", "address" :"Vancouver Canada"}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, the second one should be fine awy since the JSON.stringify fixes that. I created a DTO but still I get the same error...check UPDATE 1 in my question's post.